# Sql insert into with auto increments a single field

Tags: sql

I am running this query but it is showing `missing expression` at column 184:-

```
insert into CTI_FEATURE_ATTRIBUTES (CTI_FEATURE_ATTRIBUTE_ID
                                    ,CASE_MOTIVATION_ID
                                    ,FEATURE_SET_ID
                                    ,ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_ID
                                    ,LANGUAGE
                                    ,ATTRIBUTE_NAME
                                    ,ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
                                    ,IS_ACTIVE)
values   (select (select max(cti_feature_attribute_id) 
         from cti_feature_attributes) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY case_motivation_id)
         ,case_motivation_id
         ,feature_set_id
         ,1
         ,'en_US'
         ,'C2C_CHAT_TEMPLATE_ID'
         ,'b2dc013a-5957-4d3a-b2f3-610920f2c388'
         ,'Y' 
from     cti_feature_attributes 
where    attribute_value = 'email|phone|chat')
```

Comment: please confirm what RDBMS you are using - is it Oracle, MS SQL Server, mySQL, Access?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming MySql, a `INSERT ... SELECT` statement does not have the `values` keyword. Column 184 is the `values` keyword.

[MySql:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Similar in Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm